# Centering multiple backgrounds

Tags: html, css, background

On my website I have 3 images that make a full background, both are 1920px width. Top no-repeat, center repeat-y, bottom no-repeat.

But it looks like the center image decentralizes 1 pixel in relation to the others.. If i remove center bg, the top and bottom stay aligned.

```
body.myclass {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/top-fon-bg2.jpg) top center no-repeat, url(../images/bottom-fon-bg2.jpg) bottom center no-repeat, url(../images/fon-repeat2.jpg) center repeat-y; 
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    line-height: 1;
    min-height: 100vh; 
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You said you have 3 images, but then say both are 1920px wide. Are all 3 1920px wide, not just 2 of them?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question very well, the three images are the same width, 1920 .. If I join the three in photoshop they are perfectly aligned

Comment: I was just making sure they're all the same width. I don't really understand from your picture which part isn't lined up. What is the red box?

Comment: just a markup I made to make it easier to identify misalignment.

Testing at some resolutions lower than my 1920x1080, this misalignment does not occur.

Comment: if you press F12 and use the Select Element tool to hover over each of your images, can you see any margins or padding on any of them?

Comment: No, I only see the body of html, without any margin or padding.